# R - run each time over one cell from one column over each cell in another column

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I have a function which her input should run each time over one cell from one column over each cell in another column.

I can do it with a loop, however, I'm looking to vectorize the process or make it faster. As for now, it would take me days to finish the process. 
Ideally, it would be using `tidyverse` but any help would be appreciated.

My loop looks like that:

```
results <- data.frame(
  pathSubject1 = as.character(), 
  pathSubject2 = as.character())

i <- 1 #Counter first loop
j <- 1 #Counter second loop
#Loop over subject 1
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]) {#Start of first loop
  #Loop over subject 2  
  for (j in 1:dim(df)[1]) {#Start of second loop
    #calc my function for the subjects
    tempPercentSync <- myFunc(df$subject1[i], df$subject2[j])

    results <- rbind(
      results, 
      data.frame(
        pathSubject1 = df$value[i], 
        pathSubject2 = df$value[j], 
        syncData = nest(tempPercentSync)))
  } #End second loop
} #End first loop
```

My example function:

```
myFunc <- function(x, y) { 
  temp <- dplyr::inner_join(
    as.data.frame(x),
    as.data.frame(y),
    by = "Time")
  out <- as.data.frame(summary(temp))
}
```

Example of my dataset using `dput`:

```
structure(list(value = c("data/ExportECG/101_1_1_0/F010.feather", 
"data/ExportECG/101_1_1_0/F020.feather"), ID = c(101, 101), run = c(1, 
1), timeComing = c(1, 1), part = c(0, 0), paradigm = c("F010", 
"F020"), group = c(1, 1), subject1 = list(structure(list(Time = c(0, 
0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5), subject1 = c(9.73940345482368, 9.08451907157601, 
8.42963468832833, 7.77475030508065, 7.11986592183298, 7.24395122629289
)), .Names = c("Time", "subject1"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(Time = c(0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5), subject1 = c(58.3471156751544, 
    75.9103303197856, 83.014068283342, 89.7923167579699, 88.6748903116088, 
    84.7651306939912)), .Names = c("Time", "subject1"), row.names = c(NA, 
    6L), class = "data.frame")), subject2 = list(structure(list(
    Time = c(0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5), subject2 = c(77.7776200371528, 
    77.4139420609906, 74.9760822165258, 75.3915183650012, 77.5672070195079, 
    80.7418145918357)), .Names = c("Time", "subject2"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(Time = c(0, 0.5, 1, 
1.5, 2, 2.5), subject2 = c(101.133666720578, 105.010792226714, 
107.01541987713, 104.471173834529, 97.5910271952943, 92.9840354003295
)), .Names = c("Time", "subject2"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"))), .Names = c("value", 
"ID", "run", "timeComing", "part", "paradigm", "group", "subject1", 
"subject2"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Output should loook like:

```
                           pathSubject1
1 data/ExportECG/101_1_1_0/F010.feather
2 data/ExportECG/101_1_1_0/F010.feather
3 data/ExportECG/101_1_1_0/F020.feather
4 data/ExportECG/101_1_1_0/F020.feather
                           pathSubject2
1 data/ExportECG/101_1_1_0/F010.feather
2 data/ExportECG/101_1_1_0/F020.feather
3 data/ExportECG/101_1_1_0/F010.feather
4 data/ExportECG/101_1_1_0/F020.feather
                                                                                                                                                                           data
1 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 20, 5, 17, 14, 8, 11, 21, 6, 19, 16, 10, 13, 22, 7, 18, 15, 9, 12
2 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 21, 6, 17, 14, 8, 12, 22, 7, 19, 16, 10, 13, 20, 5, 18, 15, 9, 11
3 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 20, 5, 17, 14, 8, 11, 21, 7, 19, 16, 10, 13, 22, 6, 18, 15, 9, 12
4 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 21, 6, 17, 14, 8, 12, 22, 7, 19, 16, 10, 13, 20, 5, 18, 15, 9, 11
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `lapply` (or a related function).

What's probably taking the most time is the rbind, because at each step in your loops the entire object `results` gets slightly larger, which means it gets fully copied. With `lapply`, all results are first calculated, and only then you combine them with <del>`dplyr::rbind_list`</del> `dplyr::bind_rows`
What you get is this:

```
results <- dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(1:dim(df)[1], function(i) {
  dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(1:dim(df)[1], function(j) {
    data.frame(pathSubject1 = df$value[i],
               pathSubject2 = df$value[j],
               syncData = tidyr::nest(myFunc(df$subject1[[i]], df$subject2[[j]])))
  }))
}))
```

Does that solve your problem?

## EDIT: speeding things up

I've edited to use `bind_rows` instead of `rbind_list`, it's supposed to be faster. 
Furthermore, if you use `[[i]]` instead of `[i]` in the call to myFunc, you can drop the `as.data.frame(x)` there (and some for j/y).
Finally, you could optimize myFunc a bit by not assigning any intermediate results:

```
myFunc <- function(x, y) { 
  as.data.frame(summary(dplyr::inner_join(x, y, by = "Time")))
}
```

But my gut feeling says these will be small differences. To gain more speedup we need to reduce the actual computations, and then it matters what your actual data is, and what you need for your results.
Some observations, based on your example:

- Do we need seperate data.frames? We compare all values in `df$subject1` with those in `df$subject2`. In the example, first making one large data.frame for subject1, and then another for subject2, if needed with an extra label would speed up the join.
- Why a join? Right now the summary of the join gives only information that we could have gotten without a join as well.
- We join on `Time`, but in the example the timestamps for subject1 and 2 are identical. A check whether they are the same, followed by simply copying would be faster
- As end-result we have a data.frame, with one column containing data.frames containing the summary of the join. Is that the way you need it? I think your code could be a lot faster if you only calculate the values you actually need. And I haven't worked a lot with data.frames containing data.frames, but it could well be that `bind_rows` doesn't handle it efficiently. Maybe a simple list (as column of your data.frame) would work better, as there's less overhead.

Finally, it could be that you're unable to reveal more about your real data, or it's too complicated.
In that case I think you could look aorund for various profiling-tools, functions that can help show you where most time is being spend. Personally, I like the profvis-tool
Put `print(profvis::profvis({` *mycode* `}, interval=`*seconds*`))` around a block of code, and after it finishes execution you see which lines took the most time, and which functions are called under the hood.
In the example-code, almost all time is spent in the row-binding and making data.frames. But in real data, I expect other functions may be time-consuming.

Comment: It does the work and thank you!. However, because my real dataframe is much bigger it still takes a lot of time to run. Do you have any other ideas on how to make it faster?

Comment: I've extended my answer some more, short version: It depends, there are no real "free" speedups.

Comment: Amazing answer and thank you. Lots of great tips which helped me! unfortunately, my real function isn't like myFunc but some of your comments about it were still applicable. I cannot upload my real data or functions but moving to lapply made things quicker and allowed me to use parallel::mclapply(), which help even more.